# c# How to compare strings in class using CompareTo?

Tags: c#

sorry for previous post, so i will put my class code.

```
using System;

namespace U3_13
{
abstract class Narys
{
    public string Vardas { get; set; }
    public string Pavarde { get; set; }
    public DateTime GimimoData { get; set; }
    public Narys()
    {
    }
    public Narys(string vardas, string pavarde, DateTime gimimodata)
    {
        Vardas = vardas;
        Pavarde = pavarde;
        GimimoData = gimimodata;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Narys);
    }
    public bool Equals(Narys narys)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(narys, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.GetType() != narys.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (Vardas == narys.Vardas) && (Pavarde == narys.Pavarde);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Vardas.GetHashCode() ^ Pavarde.GetHashCode();
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
    public static bool operator <=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
    {
        return lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo(rhs.Pavarde);
    }
    public static bool operator >=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
    {
        return (lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo() >= rhs.Pavarde.CompareTo());
    }
}
}
```

So as you see, at the end of the class, those two operators <= and >= are written wrong. I need to use especially CompareTo, because my task requires it, but i don't understand how it works. Some folk said to write:

```
return lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo(rhs.Pavarde);
```

But it gives me an error, so i need help. By the way, names are called in my Lithuanian language, i will give you better understanding.

Narys - Member;

Vardas - FirstName;

Pavarde - LastName;

GimimoData - birthdate;

So i need to sort firstly by the lastname and secondly by the firstname(if 2 has same lastnames).

Comment: It goes like this: `lhs.CompareTo(rhs);`. Returns negative if lhs is less, positive if greater, zero if they are equal.

Comment: Why would you overload `>=` and `<=` ? You have already overloaded `==`, so I assume overloading `>` and `<` would give you these automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto) which says about the result of `CompareTo()`

> **Less than zero**    This instance precedes *value*.
>
> **Zero**  This instance has
>   the same position in the sort order as *value*.
>
> **Greater than zero** This instance follows *value*. -or- *value* is *null*.

so you have to replace

```
public static bool operator <=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
{
    return lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo(rhs.Pavarde); //syntax error here!
}
public static bool operator >=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
{
    return (lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo() >= rhs.Pavarde.CompareTo()); //syntax error here!
}
```

with

```
public static bool operator <=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
{
    return lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo(rhs.Pavarde) <= 0;
}
public static bool operator >=(Narys lhs, Narys rhs)
{
    return (lhs.Pavarde.CompareTo(rhs.Pavarde)) >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement IComparable if you want sort methods to use you comparison. I read between the lines, that that's what you want to do. Sorry, if I misunderstood. This is how you would do it:

```
abstract class Narys: IComparable
{
    ...
    public int CompareTo(object obj) 
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Nardys otherMember = obj as Nardys;
        if (otherMember != null) 
        {
            // Check to see if last name is the same
            if (this.Pavarde.CompareTo(otherMember.Pavarde)==0)
            {
                // Compare first names 
                return this.Vardas.CompareTo(otherMember.Vardas);
            }
            else
            {
                // Compare last names
                return this.Pavarde.CompareTo(otherMemder.Pavarde);
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Nardys");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do an `Array.Sort` or `List.Sort` on the data. There is no need to overload operators for that purpose.